# postgresql if_up_cmd for pgpool does not work

Tags: linux, postgresql

pgpool-II version 4.3.2 (tamahomeboshi)
if_up_cmd seems does not work?Below is my config file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgPTB.png)

```
use_watchdog = on
delegate_IP = '10.17.3.158' 
if_up_cmd = '/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/ip addr add $_IP_$/24 dev ens192 label ens192:1'
if_down_cmd = '/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/ip addr del $_IP_$/24 dev ens192'
arping_cmd = '/usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/arping -U $_IP_$ -w 1 -I ens192'
```

But i use it like this，nothing happened，i used ifconfig to check,virtual ip is not created,so i viewed pgpool_log.There is no information related to ‘if_up_cmd’ in the log.
It seems 'if_up_cmd' does not work? this is my logs

```
 2022-08-16 04:58:59.992: main pid 19939: LOG:  health_check_stats_shared_memory_size: requested size: 12288
    2022-08-16 04:58:59.992: main pid 19939: LOG:  memory cache initialized
    2022-08-16 04:58:59.992: main pid 19939: DETAIL:  memcache blocks :64
    2022-08-16 04:58:59.992: main pid 19939: LOG:  allocating (136981896) bytes of shared memory segment
    2022-08-16 04:58:59.992: main pid 19939: LOG:  allocating shared memory segment of size: 136981896 
    2022-08-16 04:59:00.169: main pid 19939: LOG:  health_check_stats_shared_memory_size: requested size: 12288
    2022-08-16 04:59:00.169: main pid 19939: LOG:  health_check_stats_shared_memory_size: requested size: 12288
    2022-08-16 04:59:00.169: main pid 19939: LOG:  memory cache initialized
    2022-08-16 04:59:00.169: main pid 19939: DETAIL:  memcache blocks :64
    2022-08-16 04:59:00.177: main pid 19939: LOG:  pool_discard_oid_maps: discarded memqcache oid maps
    2022-08-16 04:59:00.193: main pid 19939: LOG:  waiting for watchdog to initialize
    2022-08-16 04:59:00.193: watchdog pid 19942: LOG:  setting the local watchdog node name to "10.17.3.77:9999 Linux localhost.localdomain"
    2022-08-16 04:59:00.193: watchdog pid 19942: LOG:  watchdog cluster is configured with 2 remote nodes
    2022-08-16 04:59:00.194: watchdog pid 19942: LOG:  watchdog remote node:0 on 10.17.3.83:9000
    2022-08-16 04:59:00.194: watchdog pid 19942: LOG:  watchdog remote node:1 on 10.17.3.84:9000
    2022-08-16 04:59:00.194: watchdog pid 19942: LOG:  interface monitoring is disabled in watchdog
    2022-08-16 04:59:00.195: watchdog pid 19942: LOG:  watchdog node state changed from [DEAD] to [LOADING]
    2022-08-16 04:59:05.200: watchdog pid 19942: LOG:  watchdog node state changed from [LOADING] to [JOINING]
    2022-08-16 04:59:09.205: watchdog pid 19942: LOG:  watchdog node state changed from [JOINING] to [INITIALIZING]
    2022-08-16 04:59:10.206: watchdog pid 19942: LOG:  I am the only alive node in the watchdog cluster
    2022-08-16 04:59:10.207: watchdog pid 19942: HINT:  skipping stand for coordinator state
    2022-08-16 04:59:10.207: watchdog pid 19942: LOG:  watchdog node state changed from [INITIALIZING] to [LEADER]
    2022-08-16 04:59:10.207: watchdog pid 19942: LOG:  I am announcing my self as leader/coordinator watchdog node
    2022-08-16 04:59:14.211: watchdog pid 19942: LOG:  I am the cluster leader node
    2022-08-16 04:59:14.211: watchdog pid 19942: DETAIL:  our declare coordinator message is accepted by all nodes
    2022-08-16 04:59:14.211: watchdog pid 19942: LOG:  setting the local node "10.17.3.77:9999 Linux localhost.localdomain" as watchdog cluster leader
    2022-08-16 04:59:14.211: watchdog pid 19942: LOG:  signal_user1_to_parent_with_reason(1)
    2022-08-16 04:59:14.211: watchdog pid 19942: LOG:  I am the cluster leader node but we do not have enough nodes in cluster
    2022-08-16 04:59:14.211: watchdog pid 19942: DETAIL:  waiting for the quorum to start escalation process
    2022-08-16 04:59:14.211: main pid 19939: LOG:  watchdog process is initialized
    2022-08-16 04:59:14.211: main pid 19939: DETAIL:  watchdog messaging data version: 1.2
    2022-08-16 04:59:14.212: main pid 19939: LOG:  Pgpool-II parent process received SIGUSR1
    2022-08-16 04:59:14.213: main pid 19939: LOG:  Pgpool-II parent process received watchdog state change signal from watchdog
    2022-08-16 04:59:14.213: watchdog pid 19942: LOG:  new IPC connection received
    2022-08-16 04:59:14.213: watchdog pid 19942: LOG:  new IPC connection received
    2022-08-16 04:59:14.213: main pid 19939: LOG:  Setting up socket for 0.0.0.0:9999
    2022-08-16 04:59:14.213: main pid 19939: LOG:  Setting up socket for :::9999
    2022-08-16 04:59:14.213: life_check pid 19949: LOG:  3 watchdog nodes are configured for lifecheck
    2022-08-16 04:59:14.214: life_check pid 19949: LOG:  watchdog nodes ID:0 Name:"10.17.3.77:9999 Linux localhost.localdomain"
    2022-08-16 04:59:14.214: life_check pid 19949: DETAIL:  Host:"10.17.3.77" WD Port:9000 pgpool-II port:9999
    2022-08-16 04:59:14.214: life_check pid 19949: LOG:  watchdog nodes ID:1 Name:"Not_Set"
    2022-08-16 04:59:14.214: life_check pid 19949: DETAIL:  Host:"10.17.3.83" WD Port:9000 pgpool-II port:9999
    2022-08-16 04:59:14.214: life_check pid 19949: LOG:  watchdog nodes ID:2 Name:"Not_Set"
    2022-08-16 04:59:14.214: life_check pid 19949: DETAIL:  Host:"10.17.3.84" WD Port:9000 pgpool-II port:9999
    2022-08-16 04:59:14.236: main pid 19939: LOG:  find_primary_node_repeatedly: waiting for finding a primary node
    2022-08-16 04:59:14.264: main pid 19939: LOG:  find_primary_node: primary node is 0
    2022-08-16 04:59:14.268: pcp_main pid 19987: LOG:  PCP process: 19987 started
    2022-08-16 04:59:14.269: sr_check_worker pid 19988: LOG:  process started
    2022-08-16 04:59:14.269: health_check pid 19989: LOG:  process started
    2022-08-16 04:59:14.270: watchdog pid 19942: LOG:  new IPC connection received
    2022-08-16 04:59:14.270: main pid 19939: LOG:  pgpool-II successfully started. version 4.3.2 (tamahomeboshi)
    2022-08-16 04:59:14.270: main pid 19939: LOG:  node status[0]: 1
    2022-08-16 04:59:14.270: main pid 19939: LOG:  node status[1]: 0
    2022-08-16 04:59:14.270: main pid 19939: LOG:  node status[2]: 0
    2022-08-16 04:59:15.215: heart_beat_receiver pid 19951: LOG:  set SO_REUSEPORT option to the socket
    2022-08-16 04:59:15.215: heart_beat_receiver pid 19951: LOG:  creating watchdog heartbeat receive socket.
    2022-08-16 04:59:15.215: heart_beat_receiver pid 19951: DETAIL:  set SO_REUSEPORT
    2022-08-16 04:59:15.216: heart_beat_sender pid 19953: LOG:  set SO_REUSEPORT option to the socket
    2022-08-16 04:59:15.216: heart_beat_sender pid 19953: LOG:  creating socket for sending heartbeat
    2022-08-16 04:59:15.216: heart_beat_sender pid 19953: DETAIL:  set SO_REUSEPORT
    2022-08-16 04:59:15.216: heart_beat_receiver pid 19955: LOG:  set SO_REUSEPORT option to the socket
    2022-08-16 04:59:15.217: heart_beat_receiver pid 19955: LOG:  creating watchdog heartbeat receive socket.
    2022-08-16 04:59:15.217: heart_beat_receiver pid 19955: DETAIL:  set SO_REUSEPORT
    2022-08-16 04:59:15.217: heart_beat_sender pid 19957: LOG:  set SO_REUSEPORT option to the socket
    2022-08-16 04:59:15.217: heart_beat_sender pid 19957: LOG:  creating socket for sending heartbeat
    2022-08-16 04:59:15.217: heart_beat_sender pid 19957: DETAIL:  set SO_REUSEPORT
    2022-08-16 04:59:24.302: watchdog pid 19942: LOG:  new IPC connection received
    2022-08-16 04:59:34.336: watchdog pid 19942: LOG:  new IPC connection received
    2022-08-16 04:59:44.370: watchdog pid 19942: LOG:  new IPC connection received
```

Comment: Turns out that an external firewall blocked port 9000.